# Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

In an Argand diagram, the vertices on an equilateral triangle lie on a circle with center at the origin. One of the vertices represents the complex numbers 4 + 2i. Find the complex numbers that represent the other two vertices. Gives your answers in the form x + yi where x and y are real and exact.

Comment: $$(4+2i)\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)$$ where $\theta=60^\circ,120^\circ$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee you are wrong. angle at origin is twice the angle at circumference so it is not 60 and 120, rather it is 120 and 240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We want to rotate the given point $4+2i$ about the origin by $2\pi/3$ ($120$ degrees), and then do it again.

Rotating $z=a+bi$ about the origin (counterclockwise) by the angle $\theta$ is done by multiplying $z$ by $\cos \theta+i\sin\theta$.

**Remark:** After we have rotated $4+2i$ suitably, we don't really need to do it again. The third vertex can be found by using the fact that the sum of the three vertices is $0$.

Answer (score -1):

For one or both you may use rotation:
z2-z0=(z1-z0)*|z2-z0|/|z1-z0|*e**iA.......... where A is the angle.
And for the second (or use rotation itself) use : z1+z2(w)+z3(w**2)=0 
                                        for an equilateral triangle, where w (omega) is cube root of unity.